# onPostExecute is not being invoked

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to get the `onPostExecute()` method invoked after finishing the `doInBackground()` method but it  is not being invoked. How can I fix this?

I have debugged it and I can see the data in the `ArrayList<ItemDTO> data` object.

I appreciate any help.

**Code**

```
public class GetLLRD {
Context mContext;

public void post_selected(String json, Context context) {
    new MyAsyncTask().execute(json);
    context = this.mContext;
}

class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<ItemDTO>> {


    @Override
    protected List<ItemDTO> doInBackground(String... params) {

      .
      .
      .
      .

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ItemDTO>>() {
            }.getType();
            ArrayList<ItemDTO> data = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), listType);
      .
      .
      .
      .     


        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ItemDTO> result) {

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MyAsyncTask().execute();
                System.out.println("The method onPostExcute() in GETLLRD class was invoked  again");
            }
        }, 1*30 * 1000);

        if (result != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Map.class);
            intent.putExtra("list",result);
            mContext.startActivity(intent); 

        }else{
            Log.e("123", "Avoiding null pointer, the dat is null in the GETLLRD class!!!");
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: you are returning `null` from `doInBackground`, dont you smell something fishy there

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar Lots of tutorials are teaching to return null in doInBackground functions and use the onPostExecute one instead, just saying ^^

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar Even if you return null, the onPostExecute will run.

Comment: @jmateo did you see that he is checking whether result is null or not in `onPostExecute`

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar Yes, i do. The `onPostExecute` method is still running, isn't it? My point is to make it clear that the `onPostExecute` will run regardless of what happens in `doInBackground`.

Comment: It runs but he is not aware of that returning null is not executing his line of code which has become a dead code\

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar His question was, "I am trying to get the onPostExecute method invoked after finishing the doInBackground method but **it [is] not being invoked.** How can I fix it?"  to which you answered "you're returning null from doInBackground." Someone else might come and read this thread and think that if you return null in doInBackground, the onPostExecute doesn't run. That's all I'm trying to say.

Comment: ok then m sorry i will put it this way `onPostExecute` is invoked but you are not able to see any output because you are returning null in `doInBackground` and checking if that result is null or not in `onPostExecute` so your code is a dead code

Comment: I am used to return null from the doInBackground method but then I initialize the variable data in the method and it works. I have changed it to return data but it still does not work also onPostExecute is not being invoked.

Comment: Can you just comment the section;

`new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MyAsyncTask().execute();
                System.out.println("The method onPostExcute() in GETLLRD class was invoked  again");
            }
        }, 1*30 * 1000);
`

and than give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onPostExecute` **is being invoked.** However, as others pointed out, you're returning null in `doInBackground` and not passing the data to your `onPostExecute`

```
public void post_selected(String json, Context context) { 
    new MyAsyncTask().execute(json); 
    context = this.mContext; 
} 

class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<ItemDTO>> {


    @Override 
    protected List<ItemDTO> doInBackground(String... params) {

      . 
      . 
      . 
      . 

            Gson gson = new Gson(); 
            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ItemDTO>>() {
            }.getType(); 
            ArrayList<ItemDTO> data = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), listType); 
      . 
      . 
      . 
      .      


        return data; 

    } 

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ItemDTO> result) {

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override 
            public void run() { 
                new MyAsyncTask().execute();
                System.out.println("The method onPostExcute() in GETLLRD class was invoked  again");
            } 
        }, 1*30 * 1000); 

        if (result != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Map.class);
            intent.putExtra("list",result);
            mContext.startActivity(intent); 

        } 

    } 

}
```

Comment: I have changed the return value to data and I cant see something happening.

Comment: @TheBook Does your ItemDTO implement parcelable correctly? You cannot pass a raw list as an extra in your intent unless the class implements parcelable correctly. Can you post the code for ItemDTO?

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    protected List<ItemDTO> doInBackground(String... params) {

  .
  .
  .
  .

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ItemDTO>>() {
        }.getType();
        ArrayList<ItemDTO> data = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), listType);
  .
  .
  .
  .     


    return data;

}
```

Comment: I am used to return null from the doInBackground method but then I initialize the variable data in the method and it works. I have changed it to return data but it still does not work also onPostExecute is not being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

In `doInBackground()` instead of

```
 return null;
```

do

```
 return data;
```

Comment: I am used to return null from the doInBackground method but then I initialize the variable data in the method and it works. I have changed it to return data but it still does not work also onPostExecute is not being invoked.

Comment: just do one thing in `onPostExecute` write a toast and see if it appears.

Comment: I have add this output `Log.e("123", "the onPostExecute method was invoked from the GETLLRD class!!!");` at the begging of the method but I can not see any output in the logcat.

Comment: you wrote that in else condition i am asking you to write that as the first line in the function